# How to change the position of the labels after sorting in iphone

Tags: iphone, imageview

Hi in one the application i have a group of imageviews all are created programmatically. For these imageviews i am getting the images from one array upto this fine.

my issue is i have to implement the sorting on array data this is also done using NSSortDescriptor. But now i have to change the position of those imageviews on view based on sorted data. Upto now what i did is i am removing the existing image views from view and creating new imageviews based on the data available in array but it's taking so much of time if i have 100 elements in array. so i would like to change the position of the imageviews instead of remove and create again .

i don't have any idea regarding this can any one help me in this issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont remove the existing imageviews. One way to do is.... When the first time you are adding image from an array to your image view assign the imageView.tag=index_of_the_image_in_the_array then create a method to reload the imageviews and call it whenever you finish sorting the array. In that method, use a loop to replace the image in the imageview with the image at the corresponding index in the array.